# How to set quietperiod on Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have a pipeline with some boolean parameters. I'd like to add the `quietPeriod` as described [in the docs](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-build-step/) but I'm struggling to get the syntax right. I tried:

```
properties([
  parameters :[
    booleanParam(name: 'foo', defaultValue: false, description: 'bar')
  ],
  quietPeriod: 10
])
```

But that yields a 
`java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: must specify $class with an implementation of interface java.util.List`.

Does anyone know how to add this parameter correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Use it as an `option` in the pipeline as follows:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    options {
        quietPeriod(300) //Quiet period in seconds
    }
    stages {
        stage('1') {
            steps {
                println("Hello")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is for declarative pipeline, but the example shown by the asker uses scripted pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

From this [Jenkins ticket](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-37588) in JIRA it seems like the feature is only available by default when the Declarative Pipeline syntax is used.

As a workaround I found that doing

```
currentBuild.rawBuild.getParent().setQuietPeriod(210)
```

works like a charm. You can put it right after setting the properties, like this:

```
properties([
  parameters :[
    booleanParam(name: 'foo', defaultValue: false, description: 'bar')
  ]
])

currentBuild.rawBuild.getParent().setQuietPeriod(210)
```